# Input user name and email id and download pdf certificate with same name (name+emailid) from a folder

Tags: javascript, html

Can you correct the code below so that a user inputs his firstname and email id and his PDF certificate with same (firstname and email id) is downloaded from OOEcertificate folder

Call a JavaScript function

```
     function myFunction()
    {
        var downloadUrl = document.getElementById("url").value;
        document.getElementById("downlod").href = '/ooecertificate' + downloadUrl + '.pdf';
    }
    
    alert("You are Successfully Called the JavaScript function");  
     }
```

```
<div>
        <label>ENTER YOUR REGISTRATION ID:</label> 
        <br> </br>
        
        <label>(Your registration id is your firstname+registered email id:
                for example if your name is SAMMY DIXIT and 
                your registered email id is SAMMY.DIXIT@GMAIL.COM
                your REGISTRATION ID WILL BE: SAMMYSAMMY.DIXIT@GMAIL.COM
        </label> 
        
        <input type="text" name="url" id="url" onkeyup="myFunction()"> 
        
        <a href="/OOEcertificate" id="downlod" download><span>Download</span></a>
        
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have inputs for username & email id ? Update the code with required elements.

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to include any way to capture a "firstname" or "email id", and how do those two things get you the required URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a demo starting from your code that will fetch the value from the input box #url and will use that value to compose the url string that will be used to navigate the browser to the pdf download.

Such behaviour is obtained with `window.location.href` that I commented to make the demo working here. On its behalf it will show the url in the console.

```js
function downloadPdf(){    
    
    //fetch the registrationId from the input#url
    let registrationId = document.getElementById("url").value;        
    
    //transform the registrationId string to lower case
    registrationId = registrationId.trim().toLowerCase();
    
    const pdfUrl = `/ooecertificate/${registrationId}.pdf`;        
    
    //this is the statement to redirect the browser to the wanted url
    //now commented because it wouldn't work here on the snippet
    
    //window.location.href = pdfUrl;
    
    //on its behalf I'm writing the url on console
    console.log(pdfUrl);
}
```

```css
label.fieldLabel{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

label.fieldDescription{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;   
  border: solid 1px gray;
  padding: 1em;
}

button{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="fieldDescription">
  Your registration id is your firstname+registered email id:<br>
  For example..<br>
  if your name is SAMMY DIXIT and your registered email id is SAMMY.DIXIT@GMAIL.COM<br>
  your REGISTRATION ID WILL BE: <b>sammysammy.dixit@gmail.com</b>
  </label> 

  <label class="fieldLabel">ENTER YOUR REGISTRATION ID:</label>   

  <input type="text" name="url" id="url"> 

  <button onclick="downloadPdf();">Download</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: does not download anything nor does it show any links https://actnow.org.in/trial.html

Comment: did you uncomment the `window.location.href` portion when you brought that code in your environment?

Comment: ... and by the way I looked at the url your posted in your comment.. I saw indeed you didn't change that line and you brought syntax errors in that block that broke the function. Erase this part `alert("You are Successfully Called the JavaScript function");  }`  because you can't close the function that was already closed.

Comment: Yes corrected as suggested. Now it does not download anything but shows an 404 error. upon checking the ,ink seems to be : https://actnow.org.in/ooecertificaterajivrajiv@gmail.com.pdf .....some typo???

Comment: OOECERTIFICATE is supposed to be a folder containing all certificates

Comment: just for the sake of clarity... can you cite a valid url for downloading an existing pdf? I ask to understand how you are supposed to encode the @ to intercept the correct expected path. Because by your latest comment I understand that you are probably going to address the file, exposed through a mapped directory instead of having a real active page behind that request. I'd say it's not the best approach, but if you tell me a valid url I'll be in the position to better suit my code to your scenario

Comment: the strategy I used comes from your own code: `'/ooecertificate' + downloadUrl + '.pdf';` and I have no better hints if you don't give any

Comment: Thanks for taking pains to guide my ignorance. (1) I've a python code that generates thousands of certificates for participants. It encodes the filename with name and email id (coz sum ppl use same email to register different children) to come up with a longish but unique filename like DiegoDeVitaDiegoDaVita@gmail.com (based on the data avlble I have no better mechanism for unique file name. (2) We copy all PDF files to folder public_html\OOEcertificate where user can retrive the certificate. The link is https://actnow.org.in/trial.html and two files r avlb rajiv.pdf and rajivrajiv@gmail.pdf

Comment: I'm asking an actual url of an actual pdf that you can download... I really didn't understand how it's made a real url where you can download a pdf. The indications you gave are not enough. One single working url would just make it

Comment: This for example doesn't exist: https://actnow.org.in/OOEcertificate/SAMMYSAMMY.DIXIT@GMAIL.COM%20.pdf ... just make a valid example and it will very easy to make that code work.

Comment: CHK NOW https://actnow.org.in/OOECertificate/SAMMYSAMMY.DIXIT@GMAIL.COM.pdf

Comment: THIS ALSO : https://actnow.org.in/OOECertificate/rajivrajiv@gmail.com.pdf

Comment: Hi Diego, the code seems to be working finally, pse just check at your end. Will try with more data sets

Comment: Created this finally: https://actnow.org.in/ooecertificates.html   currently rajiv.pdf  rajivrajiv@gmail.pdf and SAMMYSAMMY.DIXIT@GMAIL.COM.pdf exist. I am so grateful to you. We are an ngo that does big things with small resoutces. hope we get you support. plse share your email id. i will need further help in styling the box and download button

Comment: if the solution solved your problem feel free to accept my answer.. and if you need further help just ask here on SO and I'm sure you'll receive help of generous people including mine

Comment: Hi Diego, just noticed a small problem: the code seems to be case sensitive : if the file stored is rajiv.pdf and i input Rajiv - it gives file not found error :(

Comment: I changed the code in the answer so that the registrationId gets trimmed and turned to lowercase before composing the url needed to fetch the pdf

Comment: thanks. is there anyway to disregard whether the input is lower or uppercase as long as it matches the filename characterwise- i mean just like filenames are case-insensitive

Comment: if the filename are insensitive depends on the filesystem holding them and how the web server deals with the http request meant to address a given file. Anyway as I commented before, the latest edit of my answer when taking the input text it just turns it to lowercase when creating the url to fetch the pdf. So if the input is SaMMySammY.dixit@gMAil.com or SAMMYSAMMY.DiXIt@gMAil.COM or any other possible permutation of uppercase, the string used in the url to fetch the pdf will always be sammysammy.dixit@gmail.com

Comment: Of course if you have files having uppercases and the request NEEDS to be case sensitive, there's no way to circumvent that unless you better define strict rules for coupling files with that id and possibly implement a dedicated endpoint aimed at returning the stream of a file given an id.

Comment: I asked because normally the PDF files generated are a mixed bunch (as they take filename automatically from excel fields): all capitals or all smalls are a mix of caps and small. similarly, the user may input any any which way caps, small or a mix of the. If we could make input and retrieved file name insensitive (just as windows does) that removes the additional care of ensuring filenames are a specific case. OR we could turn all input to smaller case and also retreived filename smaller case to achiev the same???

Comment: here we are addressing only the client side... and all that you can do here is to follow a rule. If the rule becomes: transform any input to lower case to fetch the correct filename; that's all you can do. But if there's a criteria for which on the server side it's required the exact case of the filename as how it's stored on the filesystem, the only way you can overtake the issue is crafting an endpoint on the server that will process the id and will seek for any file having the same name regardless of its case. But we are going beyond the original question.

Comment: you should ask a new question describing the details of your problem.... like how to craft an action that will return a file given a certain id that will match the filename somehow? but you should also include details on your server side.. what's the environment? the OS, the web server, the platform you are using for your application (ie.: php) and so on.

Comment: I get it. Thanks a ton. For now I will use the ready script.